# Conformal transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

Suppose that an analytic function $$w=f(z)=u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$$ maps a domain $D_{z}$ in the $z$ plane onto a domain $D_{w}$ in the $w$ plane. And let a function $h(u,v)$ with continuous partial derivates of the first and second order, be defined of $D_{w}$.

Use chain rule for partial derivates to show that if  $$H(x,y)=h(u(x,y),v(x,y))$$ then $$H_{xx} + H_{yy}=(h_{uu}(x,y) + h_{vv}(x,y)) \left|f'(z)\right|^2$$

> I have problems with this exercise, I have a confusion in as expressed $\left|f'(z)\right|^2$in terms of partial derivatives of $u,v,x,y$ as I can come to solving this problem. 
>   Thanks

Comment: Do you know the Wirtinger derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial z},\; \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $f'(z)$ is actually the Jaccobi matrix of $$(u(x,y),v(x,y)):\mathbb R^2\rightarrow{\mathbb R^2}$$